# Adding prerequisites to setup project VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, bootstrapper, prerequisites

I want to add new prerequisites to my visual studio setup project. Searching, I found the "bootstrapper manifest generator" that looks very nice, but the problem is that it doesn't work well on 64bits (the checks that it does doesnt work (I check it trying it in 32 bits pc and 64)).

The thing is that i have to install a package first if the SO is 64 bits. How can i do it?

Comment: can you explain why it does not work on 64 bit? here is a blogpost suggesting it does work: http://udaykirant.blogspot.com/2010/04/deploying-custom-made-visual-studio.html

Comment: @Wimmel I did registry checks on common adress in 32 and 64 bits, and in 32bits works perfect and in 64 bits doesnt. The msi installed doesnt work too :l